# What is the proper way to add a specialized UIViewController, such as a UIPageViewController in Monotouch?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Assuming I want to use a xib in interface builder, to add a `UIViewController` in Monotouch you can simply use the "Add new file" option in MonoDevelop and select it from the Monotouch templates.

What is the best way to add a specialized controller such as a `UIPageViewController` or a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These special controllers do not need subclassing. Most of them are not even meant to be subclassed. Just declare them in code as class variables. If, on the other hand, you still want to use them in XIBs, add a new UIViewController in MonoDevelop. Then, open the XIB in Xcode and change its class to the type you want, eg. UINavigationController.

You can do that by selecting the controller (File's Owner) and then typing the class name on the pane on the right:

[image: Select the controller]

[image: Type its class]

Comment: But that just gets me a XIB with a UIView. Now if I drag one from Xcode to the design surface, I get several UI objects and their connecting outlets. I take it Monotouch doesn't do this?

Comment: No, MonoTouch does not do that. What that gets you is a UIViewController with a UIView. The UIViewController is what the File's Owner object is. If you check its class in the above mentioned field, it is UIViewController.